# undo jquery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, z-index

I made an animation where 4 divs slide "behind" another div. I need to have a reset button that shows all the divs again so I thought I could just undo the animation. So, for example, if I animated left -100px, I thought I could just animate right +100px. That animation does nothing though. I made a js fiddle. Let me know if its too much code.

http://jsfiddle.net/R2ARv/3/

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reverse left: -100px, you do left: +100px or right: -100px.

left: -100px is equal to right: +100px.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make! I have to remind myself this often.

Comment: This only works if the previous values of left and right happen to line up perfectly.  If left was at 25px before, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use += and -=, you can make animation opposites like this:

```
left -=100px
left +=100px
```

The opposite animation of left -=100px is left +=100px.

To use the normal positioning you were using, you would have to know or save what the previous left position was and animate back to that.

So, if left was previously at zero, then these would reverse each other because these are absolute positions, not relative to the previous locations:

```
left -100px
left 0
```

Comment: i found that this works better then the previous answer but for some reason i cant mark this one as answer. You get a +1 though. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HxxUp/

Just set left back to 0.  This will reposition the elements back to where they were originally, provided that they were not absolutely positioned.

```
$("#back-to-main").click(function(){
        $("#div-link2").animate({"left": "0"}, 1500);
        $("#div-link3").animate({"left": "0"}, 1500);
        $("#div-link4").animate({"left": "0"}, 1500);
        $("#div-link5").animate({"left": "0"}, 1500);

       //other code
});
```